# Ruby on Rails 3 Book (or even website) in Korean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm coaching a Korean friend in Ruby on Rails, and I'm wondering if there are any books written in Korean about Ruby on Rails 3.

I found an old O'Reilly book in Korean about Ruby on Rails, but I'm specifically looking for a book that teaches using Rails version 3.

If nothing exists, are there any websites (i.e. forums) geared towards Korean speaking Rails programmers?

Answer (score 1):

Some Korean books are on bookstore in Korea.

but I guess he could read English book.

http://www.ruby-lang.org/ko/documentation/books/

Hyunuk Jung